# Read words separated by space & string value also contains space in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need to read default value of registry from a batch script. The name of certain item's contains some spaces. Also I want to execute for loop in batch file for one two times.

```
rem @echo OFF

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\abc\xyz pqr"

FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=<TAB>" %%A IN ('REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% 2^>nul') DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B
    set ValueValue=%%C
)
if defined ValueName (
    @echo Value Name = %ValueName%
    @echo Value Type = %ValueType%
    @echo Value Value = %ValueValue%
) else (
    @echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
)
pause
```

It Gives following output

```
rem @echo OFF

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

set KEY_NAME="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\abc\xyz pqr"

FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=<TAB>" %A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\abc\xyz pqr" 2>nul') DO (
set ValueName=%A
 set ValueType=%B
 set ValueValue=%C
)

(
set ValueName=HKEY_CURREN
 set ValueType=_USER\Software\abc\xyz pq
 set ValueValue=
)

(
set ValueName=    (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\
 set ValueType=
 set ValueValue=
)

(
set ValueName=
 set ValueType=uthor    REG_SZ    gj
 set ValueValue=
)

(
set ValueName=    Version    REG_SZ    1.4.0.0
 set ValueType=
 set ValueValue=
)

if defined ValueName (



)  else ()
Value Name =     Version    REG_SZ    1.4.0.0
Value Type =
Value Value =

pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I would like to get following output and also want that this for loop should stop once I get value of (Default)

```
(
set ValueName=(Default)
set ValueType=REG_SZ
set ValueValue=C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\
)
```

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). To use _space_ and _tab_ as delimiters, simply omit the `delims` option as they are the default anyway; `<TAB>` specifies to use those five characters literally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This commented batch code should work for this task on Windows XP and later Windows versions.

```
@echo off
rem On Windows Vista and later REG.EXE outputs without version info:

rem HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\abc\xyz pqr
rem    (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\

rem There are only spaces used to separate value name, value type and value string.


rem But REG.EXE version 3.0 outputs on Windows XP with version info:

rem ! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0
rem
rem HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\abc\xyz pqr
rem     <NO NAME>   REG_SZ  C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\

rem NOTE: There are 4 indent spaces and 2 separating tabs in REG 3.0 output line.


rem So either token 2 or token 3 contains value type REG_SZ
rem used to identify the line with the wanted information.
set "TypeToken=2"

:GetPathFromRegistry
for /F "skip=1 tokens=%TypeToken%*" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\abc\xyz pqr" /ve 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%A" == "REG_SZ" (
        set "AppPath=%%~B"
        goto HaveAppPath
    ) else if "%%A" == "NAME>" (
        set "TypeToken=3"
        goto GetPathFromRegistry
    )
)

echo Failed to read application path from registry.
pause
goto :EOF

:HaveAppPath
echo Application path is: %AppPath%
pause
```

On Windows VISTA and later Windows versions the **FOR** loop processes only 1 line from output of **REG**.

On Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, the **FOR** loop is run twice with different values for `tokens=X*` and processes more lines before getting the string value of interest because of the version information output by `reg.exe` version 3.0.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `set /?`